# JAXB-XJC: Add required args constructor for all generated classes by jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

Is there a way to add a required args constructor for org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin?

I found org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-value-constructor but it can only generate all args constructor for all generated classes.

Or can I annotate each generated class somehow with Lomboks @RequiredArgsConstructor afterwards?

Looked for plugin extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [the JAXB Annotate plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Annotate-Home) which allow you to add any annotation on any class / field.

Answer (score 0):

In the next release of [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#hisrc-basicjaxb), the [ValueConstructorPlugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/plugins/src/main/java/org/jvnet/basicjaxb/plugin/valueconstructor/ValueConstructorPlugin.java) will provide these XJC options:

- `XvalueConstructor-complete` - generate constructors for the complete set of fields.
- `XvalueConstructor-required` - generate constructors for all required fields.
- `XvalueConstructor-selected` - generate constructors for [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_selector.asp) constraints: [key](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_key.asp), [keyref](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_keyref.asp) and [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_unique.asp).

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the forked [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#hisrc-basicjaxb) project.

Comment: The updated [ValueConstructorPlugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/plugins/src/main/java/org/jvnet/basicjaxb/plugin/valueconstructor/ValueConstructorPlugin.java) is available in [HiSrc BasicJAXB Release 2.2.0](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/releases/tag/2.2.0).